# jQuery script doesnt work on higher versions

Tags: javascript, jquery, version

i have a toggle-script for the height of a list by clicking on a button.
Problem is, it works for jQuery under 1.8.3. But my website using 2.1.4 at the moment, so what is wrong on the script?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $dscr = $('#oplist'),
        $switch = $('#opbutton'),
        $initHeight = 100; // Initial height

    if( $dscr.height() <= $initHeight ) { 
        $switch.hide();
    }

    $dscr.each(function() {
        $.data(this, "realHeight", $(this).height()+20);    // Create new property realHeight
    }).css({ overflow: "hidden", height: $initHeight + 'px' });

    $switch.toggle(function() {
        $dscr.animate({ height: $dscr.data("realHeight") }, 100);
        $switch.text('show less');
    }, 
    function() {
        $dscr.animate({ height: $initHeight}, 100);
        $switch.text('show all');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/68L0ho8q/

Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: What does not work? What browser?

Comment: [Check what has been deprecated](https://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/)

Answer (score 1):

https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

> Note: This method signature was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 1.9. jQuery also provides an animation method named .toggle() that toggles the visibility of elements. Whether the animation or the event method is fired depends on the set of arguments passed.

You need to implement your own toggle method now.

```
$switch.on("click", function () {
    var isActive = !!$(this).data("active");
    $(this).data("active", !isActive);
    if (isActive) {
      //active steps
    } else {
      //not active steps
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the old code looks much more clear but this one works and this is important :D
Only problem now is, that first, i have to click twice on the button for first time and second, on my website i get the error:
"TypeError: $(...).ready is not a function
$(document).ready(function() {"

I checked which jquery version is loaded, its 2.1.3